# If I give "Contact: View All", will that give users access to every account as well?

Tags: profile, permissions

If I give a profile "Contact:  View All", does that automatically enable users in that profile to see all Accounts as well, if the Contact is 'Controlled by Parent'?

Comment: Ownership is driven by 'Controlled by Parent' so contact will not have ownership and Account will govern the ownership. Where as visibility is governed at profile level.

Answer (score 2):

The simple answer here is no. When it comes to `Controlled By Parent` what ever access is giving to the user on the parent(Account) will automatically be giving for the child(Contact), but you can increase that access on the child without increasing it on the parent.

Comment: But *only* if it's controlled by parent. If it's set to any other mode, then it would give account access because of [implicit sharing](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.draes.meta/draes/draes_object_relationships_implicit_sharing.htm).

Answer (score 0):

Thank you both @cmmoutes13!  I logged a case with SFDC and they said the same, that "Account:  View All" is not automatically granted for profiles with "Contact:  View All" but those in the profile will have access to any account associated with any contact.   If the account has no contact, those in the profile will not be able to view the account.